# Internal Hyperlink in wx.html.HtmlWindow - wxpython

Tags: html, hyperlink, wxpython, internal

I am trying to create and internal hyperlink in wx.html.HtmlWindow using an anchor and href in my html content:

```
html_content="""<a href="#resultsfound">Go To Results found</a>
<a name="resultsfound"><h2><b>RESULTS FOUND</b></h2></a>"""
```

However, when I click on the hyperlink it tries to open the location in the browser on a new tab and does not go to the corresponding location in the page.

Do you know why? Any suggestions on how to solve it?

Thanks in advance,
Zvi

Comment: I noticed that if I save the html and open it with the explorer, the internal hyperlink is working find. The problem is only in the wx.html.HtmlWindow which has being opened within the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

wx.html.HtmlWindow isn't a web browser widget. It is just for displaying HTML formatted text. You could catch the hyperlink click, download the HTML and then try to refresh the contents of the wx.html.HtmlWindow. Note however that wx.html.HtmlWindow only supports the barebone basics of HTML. It doesn't do CSS or javascript or any other fancy HTML tricks.

On the other hand, if you're on Windows, you can use the ActiveX Internet Explorer widget and do exactly what you want. Or you can try the wx Webkit widget that's not included with wxPython and is in beta.